# How does a digital sound card's electric circuit make different pitches, etc. measured in just electrons?

Tags: integrated-circuit, sound, copper, chip-design

I was wondering how hardware engineers, electrical engineers, or any and all inbetween design a circuit diagram for something that measures pitches, tones, etc. all in the form of bits/bytes and voltages carried through a substrate or such.

Is there some kind of system used to measure pitches, or half steps based on amps or volts?

For example, in Gameboy they used a simple, very limited 4-bit sound chip; are there any diagrams available to illustrate?

I'd like to understand a bit better on how the concept of sound is carried through copper.

Answer (score 2):

The "system" you are wondering about is called an ADC (Analog to Digital Converter)

This is an IC (Integrated Circuit or "chip") which "translates" between the analog and digital domains.

I assume you know how a microphone works, in that it converts sound pressure variations (from speech, music, etc) into an electrical signal. So you have an analog signal which you need to turn into information easily dealt with by a computer, i.e. binary information. This is where the ADC comes in.

There are a few types of ADC, but we'll look at the simplest to understand - th[e flash ADC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_ADC). This works simply by comparing the signal voltage level to a reference voltage and setting a bit high if it's higher than this level (a [Flip-Flop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29) handles the storage of the bit)

Say we have a 4-bit ADC like in the Gameboy. 4-bits translates to 2^4 = 16 different levels - not very fine resolution, but it will do for lo-fi recording of sound. The diagram below shows the diagram for a 2-bit flash ADC. To increase the resolution you simply extend this idea - the problem being for each twofld increase of resolution you need twice as many comparators, so beyond 10-bits (1024 comparators) it becomes difficult.

[image]

So lets say you have your 4-bit ADC, and the reference voltage (Vref in the diagram) is 1V. This means each bit is 1/16 = 0.625V. If the input signal is 0.6V, then the first 9 comparators would register high and the 4-bit output would be 1001. Ovbiously between each level the signal could actually be anywhere, so you have some uncertainty due to the quantisation, the diagram below demonstrates this for a 3-bit ADC:

[image]

**DAC**

The opposite of the ADC is the [DAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) (Digital to Analog Converter) which is used to translate the digital information back into the analog domain, for instance when you wish to play some sound through a speaker.
Again there are many types of DAC, but the simplest is probably the [R-2R type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder), which is not too dissimilar from the flash ADC in theory, just the other way around.

Basically you have a long string of resistors, set up with a certain pattern of values (you can see why it is called an R-2R) and some logic gates to drive each step. These steps are binary weighted, so each has a different influence on the output voltage:

[image]

So you end up with a stepped waveform the same as the recorded waveform shown above - the more steps, the better resolution. Also you can apply filtering to round off the square edges (remove the high frequencies caused by the edges not present in the original input waveform)

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to understand a bit better on how the concept of sound is carried through copper.

It isn't. Instead, the copper carries values that correspond to a [PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) waveform, and a [DAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) changes these values to an analog wave which is output through a speaker.